# Does including decorative HTTP headers into server reply pose extra security risk?

Tags: web-application, appsec, http

Suppose I reconfigure my HTTP server to add the following HTTP header into every reply:

```
X-Hello: Hello!
```

or some other presumably funny text.

Can this have any negative effect on the server security?

Comment: not a security issue, but extra headers do consume (some) extra bandwidth.

Answer (score 3):

No. It has absolutely zero effect.

Answer (score 3):

It depends what the header is.

Assuming it is a made-up, `X-`-prefixed, custom header, with a static value, then @Polynomial's answer is correct - it has absolutely no effect.

If you build the header value based on something else - e.g. the user's password - then that obviously would be A Bad Thing™.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't disclose info potentially valuable to a would be attacker you are fine. `X-our-awesome-stack: Software vX.YZ, Anothersoft vX.YZ, we dont believe in input santiziation!` could disclose info that you might not want to advertise. `X-Hello: What's up` type of headers are absolutely harmless.